# How to expand inline macros and/or use styles in a code block

Tags: macros, confluence

I want to achieve something like this:

```
Here is the login procedure:

+--------------------------+
| mkdir <workspace>        |
| cd <workspace>           |
| ssh {username}@server    |
+--------------------------+
```

but what I'd really like to do is put *workspace* in italics and have the {username} macro expanded.

A normal {code} block does not allow this as far as I can figure. Is there a way to do this with a {panel} or some other sort of macro? I'd still like to preserve the formatting. I'm even willing to edit the wiki markup.